# Convert Hex coding to Bytes

Tags: javascript

I have this coding:

```
*(uint32_t*) 0xFFFFFFFF8269C07Cull=0;
*(uint32_t*) 0xFFFFFFFF8269B56Full=0;
```

And I want to convert this to something similar to:

```
function doWrite(write) {
    setBase(write);
    u32[0] = 0x0006b3e9;
    u32[1] = 0x0f2e6600;
    u32[2] = 0x0000841f;
    u32[3] = 0x90000000;
    u32[4] = 0xbf495741;
    u32[5] = 0x263ffff8;
    u32[6] = 0x00000009;
    u32[7] = 0x413f8b4d;
    u32[8] = 0x5f41d7ff;
    u32[9] = 0xc0c748c3;
    u32[10] = 0x0000001a;
    u32[11] = 0xffffdfe8;
    u32[12] = 0x0f66c3ff;
    u32[13] = 0x0000441f;
    u32[14] = 0x148b4865;
}
```

But the problem is, I don't know what the first coding example is called, which is a problem for looking it up on Google.

Questions:

What is the first coding example called?
What is the second coding example called?
What tool can I use to convert the first coding to something similar to the second example?

Any answer would help a lot. I am 100% new to this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, you are trying to mimic the PS4 payload injection to enable the Developers Debug Menu/Settings. Since most customization and modding on PS4 is in C#, perhaps you should use the [C# tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) or, probably the more effective option, post your question on a more appropriate forum, which specifically deals with the modification of the PS4 software.

https://www.psxhax.com/

[Here is an additional link I found for a script which is used to sending payloads](https://www.psxhax.com/threads/playstation-4-c-code-for-sending-ps4-payloads-by-badchoicesz.1864/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: You got it, the link you posted is related to injecting the payload over TCP, but my goal here is to inject the payload over the web so the user doesn't need a PC. As you mentioned it's probably not a really appropriate site to ask this so I'll try it on some different site, thanks a lot.